# What's a way to improve this wall collision detection code to keep objects within a perimeter made of these walls

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

How can I improve the following code to keep objects from leaving a perimeter made of these walls?

Sometimes Player will collide with both a wall and an NPC (using same type of collision detection) and will end up outside of the perimeter.

I want to keep Player inside the perimeter of walls.

```
// Player Collides with Wall
        counter1 = 0;
        for (iter60 = wallArray.begin(); iter60 != wallArray.end(); iter60++)
        {
            if (Player1.rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(wallArray[counter1].rect.getGlobalBounds()))
            {
                int direction = Player1.direction;
                Player1.sprint = false;
                int arraySize1 = wallArray.size();

                switch (direction)
                {
                case 1:
                    if (Player1.rect.getPosition().y > wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)
                    {
                        if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 5)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 3.5);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 7)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 3.2);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 10)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 2.9);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 15)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 2.7);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 20)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 2.5);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 25)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 2.0);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 30)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 1.8);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 32)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y + 1.5);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (Player1.rect.getPosition().y < wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)
                    {
                        if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 5)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 3.5);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 7)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 3.2);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 10)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 2.9);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 15)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 2.7);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 20)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 2.5);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 25)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 2.0);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 30)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 1.8);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().y) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().y)) <= 32)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x, Player1.rect.getPosition().y - 1.5);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (Player1.rect.getPosition().x > wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)
                    {
                        if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 5)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 3.5, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 7)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 3.2, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 10)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 2.9, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 15)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 2.7, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 20)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 2.5, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 25)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 2.0, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 30)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 1.8, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 32)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x + 1.5, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (Player1.rect.getPosition().x < wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)
                    {
                        if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 5)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 3.5, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 7)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 3.2, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 10)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 2.9, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 15)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 2.7, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 20)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 2.5, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 25)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 2.0, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 30)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 1.8, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                        else if (abs(abs(Player1.rect.getPosition().x) - abs(wallArray[counter1].rect.getPosition().x)) <= 32)
                            Player1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition().x - 2.0, Player1.rect.getPosition().y);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            counter1++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute positions in world space to detect "in bounds" or "out of bounds" on a 2D xy axis plane.  It would be easier and less code to do line intersect testing where each wall is two points connected by a line and your collision testing line intersections with your player line of motion.  That line of motion can be current position and previous position.  For two line intersection go to this older post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you briefly describe why this method is preferable

Comment: Preferable since 1) it is a collision intersect test versus absolute position and 2) you wrote a lot of if  else statements and anytime you can write an equation to replace those nested branch loops you will have smaller and faster code.  You should really study the link.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to vector math without using vectors. Actually using vectors allows you to "find the right answer" using an equation rather than polling several possible solutions.

I would axe "direction" and replace it with "velocity" to fit nicer with vector formulas (nextPos = currentPos + velocity)

My general advice would be to create a new var "nextPos" equal to "Player1.rect.getPosition() + (direction * speed)". Then you compare nextPos to all the walls. Should there be a collision, you calculate the penetration and add that to nextPos

in pseudoCode it would be like this

```
//compute the next location as if there were no collisions
auto nextPos = Player1.rect.getPosition() + (velocity);
for(auto& w : walls){
   //for every wall, check if the new pos collides. If it does return 
   //collision resolution information (-velocity with a magnitude of 
   //penetration) but add as many params as you want
   auto penetration = w.CollidesWith(w,velocity)

   //if there is a collision, adjust the next pos and then leave
   //I'm assuming it's not possible to collide with multiple objects,
   //if it is, then don't break
   if(penetration) {nextPos += penetration.value; break;}
}
//Set the playerPosition to nextPosition
Player1.rect.setPosition(nextPos);
```

If you're interested in learning how to detect collisions and calculate their resolutions. I'd recommend looking into "collision manifolds".